# Many symbols can't be resolved in Eclipse CDT linux kernel C project

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, linux-kernel, eclipse-cdt

Just imported linux kernel C project into my Eclipse as per https://wiki.eclipse.org/HowTo_use_the_CDT_to_navigate_Linux_kernel_source

The process is really complicated to a linux kernel development newcomer like me. After going through all those steps I find that everytime I open a source file, a symbol can't be resolved issue arises something like:

> Field 'flags' could not be resolved(in kernel/async.c)
>
> Symbol '__param_str_irqfixup' could not be resolved(in kernel/irq/spurious.c)
>
> ......
>
> ......

Can anyone figure it out how to fix these. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you sure you set the include paths correctly? Please review steps 20–25.

Comment: Does the project have unresolved includes? You can check with `Project -> C/C++ Index -> Search for unresolved includes`. If there are unresolved includes, there will almost certainly be unresolved names as a result. Fix the unresolved includes (for example by adding additional paths to `Paths and Symbols | Includes`), re-build the index, that should fix most of the unresolved names.